# uWSGI with pcre support

Tags: uwsgi, pcre

I installed uWSGI with pcre support (on Heroku)
I got this message :

```
################# uWSGI configuration #################
pcre = True
kernel = Linux
malloc = libc
execinfo = False
ifaddrs = True
ssl = True
zlib = True
locking = pthread_mutex
plugin_dir = .
timer = timerfd
yaml = embedded
json = False
filemonitor = inotify
routing = True
debug = False
capabilities = False
xml = libxml2
event = epoll
############## end of uWSGI configuration #############
```

However, when i launch it using uwsgi --pcre-jit

I got this:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.10 (64bit) on [Mon Jun 22 22:51:56 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.2 on 22 June 2015 22:37:39
os: Linux-3.13.0-49-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 10 20:11:33 UTC 2015
nodename: 2bba099f-37e1-4ee2-aaa2-2400a68e6530
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 4
current working directory: /app
detected binary path: /app/.heroku/python/bin/uwsgi
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 256
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 10000
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
The -s/--socket option is missing and stdin is not a socket.
```

pcre jit disabled. Why uwsgi does not use pcre?

Comment: pcre-jit is an optimization that must be supported in the pcre library. Probably heroku (or the buildpack you use for pcre) has changed

Comment: Damn, this was working a few weeks ago with the regular python buildpack and the new cedar stack. The uwsgi internal routing does not work anymore.

Comment: jit is only an optimization,it is not required for uWSGI internal routing, any pcre version will be good for it

Comment: Heroku Cedar-14 contains libpcre3 (1:8.31-2ubuntu2), libpcre3-dev, (1:8.31-2ubuntu2) and libpcrecpp0 (1:8.31-2ubuntu2). It should work. (it was working...) Do you mean that "pcre jit disabled" just means that only the jit optimization is disabled? How can i check that at least one pcre library is loaded?

Comment: I confirm : pcre is working. Thanks!